# Finding indices for all instances of element in array

Tags: arrays, swift

This question is pretty simple honestly. Is there a way to find all occurrences of an element in an array in swift without looping through it? It seems like all the built in methods only return the index of the first occurrence, not all of them.

It would be lovely to have a `index(where:)` style approach that returns an array of indices. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance for any input!

**Edit:**

Thanks everyone for the replies! Looks like I should have been clearer on this. The way I'm currently doing this is an extension that looks very similar to the one matt posted below. I understand that any method for doing this will have to loop through the array under the hood, I was more wondering if there was a built in method buried in the language somewhere that I was unaware of. It just seems like something someone would commonly want to do. Looks like the extension is here to stay!

Comment: *"Is there a way to find all occurrences of an element in an array in swift without looping through it"* - **no**! *If* a builtin exists for it, it will loop as well.

Comment: a framework is an encapsulation for long code , create an array extension and use it anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own indices method that takes a predicate as parameter:

**Xcode 11 • Swift 5.1**

```
extension Collection where Element: Equatable {
    func indices(of element: Element) -> [Index] { indices.filter { self[$0] == element } }
}
```

---

```
extension Collection {
    func indices(where isIncluded: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Index] { try indices.filter { try isIncluded(self[$0]) } }
}
```

---

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2]
let search = 1

let indices = arr.indices(where: { $0 == search })
// or simply
// let indices = arr.indices { $0 == search }
print(indices)   // [0, 3, 5, 9, 10]

let indices2 = arr.indices(of:  search)
print(indices2)   // [0, 3, 5, 9, 10]

let string = "Hello World !!!"
let indices3 = string.indices(of: "o")
print(indices3)  //  [Swift.String.Index(_compoundOffset: 16, _cache: Swift.String.Index._Cache.character(1)), Swift.String.Index(_compoundOffset: 28, _cache: Swift.String.Index._Cache.character(1))]
```

Comment: I like this method a lot. Good idea using a closure to provide fine grained control over the process.

Answer (score 9):

> Is there a way to find all occurrences of an element in an array in swift without looping through it

No, obviously not. No magic power can glance at the whole array at once.

*You* don't have to do the looping, but no matter what you do, you will at least have to ask Swift to loop through the array *for* you. *Someone* — be it you or Swift — must loop.

For example, this may *look* elegant and pithy:

```
    let arr = [1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2]
    let target = 1
    let indices = arr.enumerated().reduce(into: []) {
        if $1.1 == target {$0.append($1.0)}
    }
    // indices is [0, 3, 5, 9, 10]
```

... but guess what `reduce` does? It loops.

---

By the way, I would suggest encapsulating this sort of thing as a generalized extension:

```
extension Collection where Element : Equatable {
    func allIndices(of target:Element) -> [Int] {
        let indices = self.enumerated().reduce(into: [Int]()) {
            if $1.1 == target {$0.append($1.0)}
        }
        return indices
    }
}
```

That way, you can talk like this whenever you want all the indices:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2]
let indices = arr.allIndices(of: 1)
```

Comment: he asks about swift build-in methods whether exist or not --- not the looping logic

Comment: @Sh_Khan How do we know that?

Comment: he asks the existence of something like **index(where:)**

Comment: better to use the tuple naming to improve readability `if $1.element == target { $0.append($1.offset) }`

Comment: @Sh_Khan so you want matt an me to remove all the code from our answers and only leave the "no"? You can be pretty sure OP wants to know *how* to do it. Same way you ask "can you do X for me" and the appropriate response is not a "yes" and be done - or "can you tell me the time?" _ "yes".

Comment: @LeoDabus I didn't know about the tuple naming for `enumerated`. Have we always had that?

Comment: @matt I think since Swift 3

Comment: `func allIndices(of target: Element) -> [Index] {
        return indices.filter({ self[$0] == target })
    }`

Comment: Note that using `enumerated` you are returning an `Int` instead of a `String.Index` if you use this method with  a `String`

Answer (score 4):

I would propose the following way:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2]
let search = 1
let indices = arr.enumerated().flatMap { $1 == search ? $0 : nil }
print(indices)
```

> [0, 3, 5, 9, 10]

Comment: But it's only fair to point out that this has no advantage over manually looping through the `enumerated` pairs, accumulating the found matches' indices _yourself_.

Comment: Note that this returns the offset not the index. It can be easily misused when applied to just a slice of the array. You should always work with the collection indices.